# Bounding box (left, top, height, width) to PHP x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinates?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am using AWS Rekognition to detect faces in an image. When a face is detected it outputs bound box information so that you can use it to draw one on the image. However, these are left, top, height, and width and the numbers are decimal floats.

Here is an example of the output:

```
{ "BoundingBox": { "Width": 0.06649632751941680908203125, "Height": 0.102198123931884765625, "Left": 0.52286112308502197265625, "Top": 0.2651510536670684814453125 }
```

And to draw the boxes on the image I do this:

```
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($destinationPath . $im . '.png');
                    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                    imagerectangle($im, $result['FaceDetails']['0']['BoundingBox']['Top'] * $width, $result['FaceDetails']['0']['BoundingBox']['Left'] * $height, $result['FaceDetails']['0']['BoundingBox']['Height'] * $width, $result['FaceDetails']['0']['BoundingBox']['Width'] * $height, $white);
                    imagepng($im, $destinationPath . $im . '.png', 9);
```

However, the box never matches the face. Is there an easier way to convert these variables or calculate them? I have looked everywhere and could really use some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($destinationPath . $im . '.png');
                    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                    foreach ($result['FaceDetails'] as $r) {
                        $widtho = $r['BoundingBox']['Width'];
                        $heighto = $r['BoundingBox']['Height'];
                        $left = $r['BoundingBox']['Left'];
                        $top = $r['BoundingBox']['Top'];
                        $w = $width * $widtho;
                        $h = $height * $heighto;
                        $x = $left * $width;
                        $y = $top * $height;
                        imagerectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $w, $y + $h, $white);
                        imagepng($im, $destinationPath . $im . '.png', 9);
                    }
```